# Lyapunov function for a second order system involving trigonometric functions

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am studying the stability of the following system:

\begin{aligned}
 \dot{x}_{1} &= -x_{1}^{2} - \sin x_{2}\\
 \dot{x}_{2} &= x_{1} - \frac{\cos x_{2}}{x_{1}}\\
\end{aligned}

The system itself has 2 equilibrium points:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
 x_{1} &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\\
 {x}_{2} &= -\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
 x_{1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\\
 {x}_{2} &= -\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Which I confirmed by analyzing the [phase portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRJRf.png) of the system:

[image]

Through linearization, I determined that the left equilibrium point is an *unstable focus* and the right one is a *stable focus* according to the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix of the system evaluated in each equilibrium point.

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  \lambda_{1} &= 1.2613 + 1.1124i\\
  \lambda_{2} &= 1.2613 - 1.1124i\\
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\qquad
\text{,}
\qquad
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  \lambda_{1} &= -1.2613 + 1.1124i\\
  \lambda_{2} &= -1.2613 - 1.1124i\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

As far as I know, it is possible to make a change of coordinates and translate the stable equilibrium point to the origin. So, my goal consists in finding an appropriate Lyapunov function for determining the stability of the origin (after the change of coordinates), employing Lyapunov's second method.

Among others, here are some candidate functions I've tried so far without satisfactory results:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  V(x) &= x_{1}\sin x_{1} + \frac{1}{2}x_{2}^{2}\\
V(x) &= \frac{1}{2}x_{1}^{2} + (1-\cos x_{2})\\
V(x) &= x_{1}\sin x_{1} + (1-\cos x_{2})\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I got stuck trying to find a Lyapunov function due to the trigonometric functions involved in the original system. Could someone give me a suggestion or hint?

Comment: Note that $x_2=-\frac{\pi}{4}+k\,\pi$ gives an infinite family of fixed points.

Comment: Yes, as Miguel mentioned, this system has an infinite number of equilibrium points. All those with $x_1<0$ are unstable whereas the others are stable. So there is no hope to find a global Lyapunov function as there is no globally stable equilibrium point here. Finally, the first and third candidate Lyapunov function you consider fail to be positive for all values of the state. Why are you trying to prove this result? I am asking because it may not be that important depending on your goals.

Comment: @KBS Does this mean that I cannot determine stability using Lyapunov's second method? What about local stability?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If you want to show that the equilibrium points with $x_1 > 0$ are locally stable, you already have done that with your linearization. As mentioned above there are multiple equilibrium points that are stable, so you will only be able to show that they are locally stable (what you already know from the linearization). So what are you trying to do? Are you trying to find a region of convergence by using a Lyapunov function?

Comment: AFAIK there is no systematic way to find Lyapunov functions. They often stem from physical considerations: the system "dissipates energy" thus it is important to know if the ODE is a model of some physical system.

Comment: @EduardoSalazarHidalgo Yes, you can establish local stability properties and possibly some estimate for the basin of attraction of the equilibrium points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stable equilibrium point $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}, - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, the state variable transformation can be constructed as
$$
\begin{aligned}
 y_{1} &= x_{1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \\
 y_{2} &= x_{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
for which there is an inverse
$$
\begin{aligned}
 x_{1} &= y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \\
 x_{2} &= y_{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
such that system model
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{x}_{1} &= - x_{1}^{2} - \sin(x_{2}) \\
 \dot{x}_{2} &= x_{1} - \frac{\cos(x_{2})}{x_{1}} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
in the new coordinates has the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{y}_{1} &= - \left(y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\right)^{2} - \sin\left(y_{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
 \dot{y}_{2} &= y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} - \frac{\cos\left(y_{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
that can be expanded to
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{y}_{1} &= - y_{1}^{2} - 2^{\frac{3}{4}} y_{1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \sin\left(y_{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \cos\left(y_{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
 \dot{y}_{2} &= y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} - \frac{\cos\left(y_{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \sin\left(y_{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
and then be simplified to
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{y}_{1} &= - \left(y_{1} + 2^{\frac{3}{4}}\right) y_{1} - \left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \frac{\sin\left(y_{2}\right)}{y_{2}}\right] y_{2} + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \cos\left(y_{2}\right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \dot{y}_{2} &= y_{1} - \left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} \frac{\sin\left(y_{2}\right)}{y_{2}}\right] y_{2} - \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \cos\left(y_{2}\right)}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} . \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, the above modeling equations is represented in the nonlinear state-space format
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{\mathbf{y}} &= \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{B} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{y}) \\
 \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y}_{1} \\
\dot{y}_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
- \left(y_{1} + 2^{\frac{3}{4}}\right) & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sin\left(y_{2}\right)}{y_{2}} \\
1 & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} \frac{\sin\left(y_{2}\right)}{y_{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(y_{2}\right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}} \cos\left(y_{2}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} . \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking the limit of $\dot{\mathbf{y}}$ as $y_{1} \rightarrow 0$ and $y_{2} \rightarrow 0$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y}_{1} \\
\dot{y}_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
- 2^{\frac{3}{4}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
1 & - \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \\
 \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y}_{1} \\
\dot{y}_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
- a & - b \\
1 & - c \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \\
 \dot{\mathbf{y}} &= \mathbf{A} \mathbf{y} . \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since this is a linear system, we postulate there exists a quadratic Lyapunov function $V(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y}^{T} \mathbf{P} \mathbf{y}$, where $\mathbf{P}$ is a real symmetric positive-definite matrix. The derivative of V along the trajectories of $\dot{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}$ is given by
$$
\dot{V}(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y}^{T} \left(\mathbf{P} \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{P}\right) \mathbf{y} = - \mathbf{y}^{T} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{y}
$$
where $\mathbf{Q}$ is also a symmetric positive-definite matrix defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{Q} &= 2 (a + c) (a c + b) \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
and $2 (a + c) (a c + b) = 9 \sqrt[4]{2} > 0$. Solving the Lyapunov equation
$$
\mathbf{P} \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{P} = - \mathbf{Q}
$$
then the unique solution, $\mathbf{P}$ is obtained
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P} &= \begin{bmatrix}
c^2 + a c + b + 1 & a - b c \\
a - b c & a^2 + a c + b^2 + b \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}.
$$
This approach can be used to establish the local stability for the stable equilibrium point.